# Can't able to save and display camera images in gridView in flutter using image_picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am creating a widget in which I want to display a gridview of image clicked through mobile camera at runtime. I had used image_picker package from flutter. But it is only working for picking image from gallery and everytime I click image it crashes.

```
class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput>
with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
// list of images 
final List<File> _imageFileList = [];
   final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
```

Function for picking image from camera using image_picker

```
final imageFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
      if (imageFile == null) return;
      File tmpFile = File(imageFile.path);
      final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final fileName = basename(imageFile.path);
      final localFile = await tmpFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
      // setState(() {
      //   _imageFileList.add(localFile);
      //
      // });
     _pickImageGall(ImageSource.gallery);
    }
```

function for picking images from the gallery of phone

```
Future<void> _pickImageGall(ImageSource imageSource) async {
 final _pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
  if (_pickedImage != null) {
    setState(() {
     _imageFileList.add(File(_pickedImage.path));
    });
   }
  }
```

and in the ui there is a gridview to display the images in which the last index is a input widget where there is two IconButton one for camera input and other for gallery input. As I am making this thing for the first time I am confused how to procedure will be . I had try to implement every solution from the stackoverflow but none worked for me. Please give the solution.

Comment: Where's the crash log?

Comment: There is no error but desired output is not working

Comment: `everytime I click image it crashes.` - This means there's a crash and the log of it can tell what's wrong.

Comment: Can't tell beacuse I am using via apk and when I use phone instead of emulator it lost connection when camera is opened.

Comment: Did noone ever built this stuff ? strange!

Comment: Connect your phone via ADB -> Open Android Studio -> Open Logcat  -> Check the log in it and provide the crash log (Highlighted in Red). It doesn't matter if the app is from APK or direct, the logcat logs everything of every app, even of system apps.

Comment: If you don't know about it, this is a very important thing you should know so leave all and learn Logcat and basic debugging using Android studio first. Leave Visual studio code, that's just a jack of all trades.

Comment: Thats a problem whenever I start to click photo it shows lost connection to the device usually and when by luck it run it had never shown any error or warning so cant debig also.